# How to scrape specific text in <p> elements with Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I know how to scrape the entire p element, but I want to put all three parts of the location in different categories. I plan to do this by scraping them all individually and putting them into a csv file individually.

Here's the Html with an example location:

```
<p>
70 Donald E Hiltz Connector Road
<br>
Kentville, NS
<br>
B4N 3V7
</p>
```

Comment: Try `.split("<br>")`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.

The best solution would be, if you owned the site or if the html is yours, you can just put id in the p tags and get the contents with Beautiful soups `find(id="")` function.
otherwise you just could get the whole data and see if you could get the contents with string functions like `yourstring.split()` This could be useful if your data was structured like the example all the time, so you could just use the words and their sequence.
Im sorry that i can't post a comment because of my low reputation, but it would be better if you could be more clear and say how you scrape your data, in what form and so on

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will go about:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p> 70 Donald E Hiltz Connector Road <br> Kentville, NS <br> B4N 3V7 </p>'''

soup =BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

# replace `br` tag with pipe that we use to split data
_ = [br.replace_with('|') for br in soup.find_all('br')]

data = [text.strip() for text in soup.find('p').text.split('|')]

print(data)
```

Results

```py
['70 Donald E Hiltz Connector Road', 'Kentville, NS', 'B4N 3V7']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<p>
70 Donald E Hiltz Connector Road
<br>
Kentville, NS
<br>
B4N 3V7
</p>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
texts = doc.p.getText('|').split('|')
print (texts)
```

Result:

```
['70 Donald E Hiltz Connector Road', 'Kentville, NS', 'B4N 3V7']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples